# Removing a body with box2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I need to remove a certain vector from my world bounds, for example only the left one.
(box2d+cocos2d iphone)

This is how I set the bounds:

```
screenBorderShape.Set(lowerLeftCorner, lowerRightCorner);
screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
screenBorderShape.Set(lowerRightCorner, upperRightCorner);
screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
screenBorderShape.Set(upperRightCorner, upperLeftCorner);
screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
screenBorderShape.Set(upperLeftCorner, lowerLeftCorner);
screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
```

How can I remove the left one ONLY?

I know this :

```
screenBorderBody->DestroyFixture(b2Fixture *fixture)
```

But I need to do that later on, so can I reach that fixture (having the body pointer) without saving this specific one as a global?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

screenBorderShape.Set(lowerRightCorner, upperRightCorner);
    screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);

Name this fixture as left fixture or left wall....

After this you can use screenBorderBody->DestroyFixture(<#b2Fixture *fixture#>)

...

The way is

groundBox.Set(b2Vec2(X1/PTM_RATIO,Y1/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(X2/PTM_RATIO, Y1/PTM_RATIO));
    bottomFixture = groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBoxDef);

and then remove bottom fixture (left in your case)

In caseyou just want to cancel the collisions do it by setting category or mask bits that way